# Deprecated Method: getPreferenceScreen

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, sharedpreferences, preferences, preferenceactivity

I want to enable/disable a checkboxPreference proramtically, depending on a value from a ListPreference. The method getPreferenceScreen is deprecated:

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
if ( key.equals(PREF_KEY_VORL) ) {

    Log.v("PreferenceChange", "Vorlage: " + prefs.getString(key,"Sonstige"));

    if(prefs.getString(key,"Sonstige").equals("Sonstige"))  //Vorlage == Sonstige
    {
        getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_KEY_UTMREF).setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(PREF_KEY_UTMREF).setEnabled(false);
    }
}
}
```

Also I get an error in the line, where I call getPreferenceScren.find....

It crashes with a NullPointerExeption in this line

thx tom

Edit: 
I'm using Fragments, I have a fragement class, where I build my preference screen:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from a XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.settings);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

the method is deprecated because you should be using `PreferenceFragment` however API's below 11 will still need to use the old way as there is no `SupportPreferenceFragment` to use. A method being deprecated should not effect your app unless the method is completely removed from the SDK.

You are getting a null exception probably because it cannot find the key you gave it

Comment: I'm using fragments, so what should I do now? (see edit)

Comment: you are using `PreferenceFragment` and you are still getting that the method is deprecated?

Comment: yes, but maybe I'm doing something wrong...How can I enable/disable such a checkBox?

Comment: well im pretty sure you should be casting to the object you want example `CheckBoxPreference box = (CheckBoxPreference) getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("key");` and then using the checkbox value to enable/disable. Its been a while since I used PreferenceFragment/Activity I cant really remember